# Quadratic optimization problem where the variable is a binary matrix.

Tags: optimization, operations-research, quadratic-programming, constraint-programming

I have the following optimization problem that I want to solve (note that the $X$ variable consists of a *binary* matrix subject to a single constraint).

First, some definitions:

My $X$ variable:
$$
X = \underset{n\times m}{\underbrace{\pmatrix{
x_{11} & x_{12} & \dots &x_{1m} \\
x_{21} & \ddots \\
\vdots & & \ddots\\
x_{n1} & & & x_{nm}
}}}\ \ \ \ \ x_{ij} \in \{ 0,1 \}
$$

Other entities (constants) that I need to compute the cost function:

$$
A = 
\underset{n\times m}{\underbrace{\pmatrix{
a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots &a_{1m} \\
a_{21} & \ddots \\
\vdots & & \ddots\\
a_{n1} & & & a_{nm}
}}}\ \ \ \ \ a_{ij} \in \{ 0,1 \}
$$

$$
\mathbf{r} = \underset{m\times 1}{\underbrace{\pmatrix{r_1 \\ r_2 \\ \vdots \\ r_m}}}\ \ \ r_i = \frac{1}{\overline{r}}\ \ \ \ \forall i\in\{1,\dots,m\}
$$

$$
\mathbf{o}^{(m)} = \underset{m\times 1}{\underbrace{\pmatrix{o_1 \\ o_2 \\ \vdots \\ o_m}}}\ \ \ o_i = 1\ \ \ \ \forall i\in\{1,\dots,m\}
$$

$$
\mathbf{o}^{(n)} = \underset{n\times 1}{\underbrace{\pmatrix{o_1 \\ o_2 \\ \vdots \\ o_n}}}\ \ \ o_i = 1\ \ \ \ \forall i\in\{1,\dots,n\}
$$

$$
\mathbf{t} = \underset{m\times 1}{\underbrace{\pmatrix{t_1 \\ t_2 \\ \vdots \\ t_m}}}\ \ \ t_i = \overline{t}\ \ \ \ \forall i\in\{1,\dots,m\}
$$

$$
\mathbf{p} = \left(A - X\right)^T\mathbf{o}^{(n)}
$$

I have just one constraint that is:
$$
X\mathbf{o}^{(m)} = \mathbf{t}
$$

The cost function that we want to *minimize* is:

$$
J = \frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{p}\right)^T\left(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{p}\right)
$$

The search space is pretty huge since the number of solutions is ${\binom{n}{\overline{t}}}^m$. I'm pretty sure I can try to find a reasonable solution by using *genetic algorithms*, but is it possible to formulate and solve the problem by means of *quadratic programming*?

The main issue here is that I don't think I can rearrange my equations as [follows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) (and $X$ in my case is a matrix, instead of a vector):

$$
J = \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^TQ\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{x}
$$
s.t.
$$
A\mathbf{x} \le \mathbf{b}
$$

Comment: Try to write it in a more compact way. It looks long and confusing.

Comment: also, you should state clearly what variables are known ( so constants ) and what variables are not known. Maybe just $x$ is the unknown but it's not clear.

Comment: If $y=r-p$ (this is a linear constraint) then your objective is $\frac12 y^Ty$ so your problem is quite trivially a binary QP, or binary SOCP, so you can use any solver capable of mixed-integer QP or SOCP. A modeling language like CVXPY, CVX or YALMIP will let you write the whole thing in just a few lines of code. It may still be very hard to solve to optimality though.

Comment: Extending the comment by @MichalAdamaszek: Since your constraints are linear in $X$ and your objective function is quadratic in $X,$ you can linearize the objective function by introducing additional variables and inequality constraints and then solve it using a mixed-integer *linear* program solver. Some solvers will handle the linearization for you; some may require you to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @MichalAdamaszek, so I guess I need to rearrange my constraint in order to obtain something that resembles $A\mathbf{y} \le \mathbf{b}$. Is it right? Unfortunately, I don't have much experience in QP, so if you can point me to any useful resource it would be really great.

Comment: Thanks @prubin, I will investigate on that too!